# How to restore Apex Application crashed while installing Plugin?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am developing an application using Apex 5 version. While installing a plugin called excel2collection from `apex-plugin.com` to shared components, the whole application is replaced with the plugin and now I don't see any pages or regions, it is replaced with same application number with different name. I couldn't figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin download (it helps to reference the source - [excel2collections on apex-plugin.com](http://apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/process-type-plugin/excel2collections_271.html)) contains a demo application (f101.sql) and the actual plugin. The plugin is a process type plugin, so it can not overwrite an application. You probably installed the demo application and replaced your own application with it.
First of all that should serve to warn you to be careful with what you do and install.

To get back your own application you only have a few options now.

1. Try to flashback your application through the export. Edit the
   application, then go to Export/Import, choose Export. On the export
   page, use the "As of" field to attempt to export the application as
   it was x minutes ago (minutes!!). 
   [image: Application export - As of]
   It helps to read the help though, as you may run into a limitation.

   > **Help on "As of" item on "Export" page:**
   >   Specify a time in minutes to go to back to for your export. This
   >   option enables you to go back in time in your application, perhaps to
   >   get back a deleted object. This utility uses the dbms_flashback
   >   package. The timestamp to SCN (system change number) mapping is
   >   refreshed approximately every 5 minutes, so you may have to wait that
   >   long to get to the version you are looking for. The time undo
   >   information is retained by the startup parameter undo_retention
   >   (default 3 hrs), but this only influences the size of the undo
   >   tablespace. While two databases may have the same undo_retention
   >   parameter, you can go back much further in time on the database with
   >   less transactions since the transactions are not filling the undo
   >   tablespace, forcing older data to be archived.

   If you cannot flashback far enough (or not at all...)...
2. Install a backup of your application. Maybe you took a recent export
   of it.
3. roll back the database. Ask the DBA to restore the database to a
   hopefully recent backup.

If none of these are an option you're out of luck and nothing can be done. Rebuild and pay attention in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot .i tried all the options.Unfortunately my application is crashed few days before so its my bad luck and have to rebuild again